# ¿Como actualizar estructura de base de datos postgres sin alterar sus registros?

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

lo que necesito en este momento es una forma de actualizar la estructura de la base de datos sin alterar sus registros, tengo una base de datos que no ha sido tocada por mucho tiempo conforme las versiones del sistema que manejo actualmente, por ende necesito actualizar la estructura de esa base de datos con la versión mas nueva pero sin alterar los datos en esa base de datos.
El motor de bases de datos que manejo es postgres en su versión 8.2

Comment: Entonces no quieres alterar la estructura de la BD, quieres actualizar el manejador de la BD ¿Cierto?

Comment: no amigo, necesito eso, actualizar la estructura sin alterar los datos

Answer (score 0):

## sí, se puede

Si tu base de datos utiliza tipos de tablas y tipos de datos estándar no vas a tener ningún problema. El camino es:

1. Hacer un dump de la base de datos (se puede hacer un backup con en `pgAdmin` o utilizar el pg_dump desde la línea de comandos.
2. Levantar ese archivo dump en la máquina que tenga instalado el nuevo postgres (actualmente versión 9.6). Eso se puede hacer con pg_restore o a mano con el `pgAdmn`.

Si tienes algún problema al hacer el restore vuelve a preguntar en función del mensaje y/o código de error recibido

### Los datos quedan bien

Puede haber problemas con alguna función o nombre de columna, pero los datos seguro van a quedar restaurados en forma correcta.

### Precaución

Por las dudas, hasta que no tengas la nueva versión funcional no borres la máquina ni desinstales el posgres viejo

Comment: otra precaucion es que la estructura nueva no debe existir un campo not null por que le dara error ,se debe actualizar la db y luego colocarle las restricciones y foreign key nuevos luego que la db alla cargado el dump y se le coloque un valor por defecto

Answer (score 0):

que creo que estas revolviendo dos cosas, por un lado esta la actualizacion del motor de base de datos, que la unica manera de hacer es haciendo el DUMP correspondiente e insertarlo en el nuevo motor.

La mejor manera de hacer esto es probando la migracion en otra maquina distinta para no correr riesgos.

Por otra parte tienes el cambio de estructura de tus tablas

Para esto yo te recomiendo un proceso manual.

**Primera Opcion**

Una manera que se puede hacer es haciendo dumps separados de estructura y datos; luego modificar el dump de estructura con los cambios requeridos y posteriormente introducir los dumps en en motor de base de datos

**Segunda Opcion**

Otro puede ser generando nuevas estructuras desde tus tablas existentes haciendo CAST en los datos que lo requieras.

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS ( SELECT <campo1>::NUMERIC AS nuevocampo1);
```

[Manual PortgreSQL 9.6 - CREATE TABLE AS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtableas.html)

y posteriormente cuando tengas todas tus tablas, crear todas las referencias y demas attributos entre tus tablas.

**Tercera Opcion**

O utilizando herramientas que te facilitan la exportacion e importacion de datos, yo he utilizado esta herrramienta y se me hace fabulosa

[SQL Manager for PortgreSQL](https://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/postgresql/manager)